# How to access class module from object instance?

Tags: python, python-2.5

I want to access module-level variables of the module that defines the class the instance is derived from.  I only have the instance to work from.  I tried `self.__class__.__module__[<some var>]` but unlike the `__class__` attribute which returns the class object, `__module__` just returns a string name, not the module object itself.  How can I get the module object in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__module__` attribute can be used as a key in the [`sys.modules` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
import sys
class_module = sys.modules[instance.__class__.__module__]
```